# Free jqGrid 4.8.0 - restore grid toolbarfilter values

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm trying to restore the grid after doing GridUnload to it's previous state in terms of filter, sort, group etc'.  I successfully achieved restoring  all of those, but missing some visual aspects within the grid that are not part of the data i'm restoring, and as such I can't see them.

For example, I do restore the filter values (toolbarfilter), but I can't see the filters values in the toolbar. (they are there, as I can restore them using $("#gview_"+$grid.attr('id')+' #' + inputId).val(column.data), but I don't know how to make them re-appear without iterate manually over them.

Thanks,

Tal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I restored the toolbarfilter by doing the following:

1. I saved all the rules into a temporary varible (barFilter).
2. After grid restoration, I added a new function that gets the barFilter and extract the values into their places restoreToolbarFilter($('#'+gridName),barFilter);:

```js
regexEscape = function(s) {
   return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

function restoreToolbarFilter($grid,searchParams){
 
    
    for (key in searchParams) {
     // Restore the search input string
     var column = searchParams[key];
     
     inputId = regexEscape('gs_' + column.field);
    
     
     $("#gview_"+$grid.attr('id')+' #' + inputId).val(column.data);
     
     // Restore the search filter type and operator symbol
     operator = $("#gview_"+$grid.attr('id')+' #' + inputId).closest('tr').find('.soptclass');
     $(operator).attr('soper', column.op);
     operands = {  "eq":"==",
         "ne":"!",
         "lt":"<",
         "le":"<=",
         "gt":">",
         "ge":">=",
         "bw":"^",
         "bn":"!^",
         "in":"=",
         "ni":"!=",
         "ew":"|",
         "en":"!@",
         "cn":"~",
         "nc":"!~",
         "nu":"#",
         "nn":"!#" };
     $(operator).text(operands[column.op]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you **already filled** all fields of the filter toolbar then you can just call `triggerToolbar` method. Be carefully that the method is method of DOM element. So you can just call

```
$grid[0].triggerToolbar();
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is triggerToolbar fires another post request to the server? If that's the case, I will result in two consecutive calls to the server that results with same data. All I need is to "show" the values within the toolbar.

Comment: @Tal: It depend on which searching options (or the options of the `filterToolbar` you use). I personally use always `stringResult: true` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching). In the case the request to the server contains `filters` parameter in the same format like in case of advanced searching (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options)), but with one only group of cause.

Comment: @Tal: `triggerToolbar` just read the values from the filter toolbar, add options like `filters` to `postData` parameter, set `search` parameter to `true` and the trigger `reloadGrid` to make request to the server or to apply local filtering.

Comment: I use searchResult:true. If trigger toolbar calls reloadGrid, that means I go once again to the server. I already went once to the server while I restored the grid (during the initial of it), now I only want to "show" the filter values. If the only way to achieve that is to reload the grid again, that a penalty in performance, kind of.

Comment: @Tal: Sorry, but I then don't understand what you already implemented and what you still need. You wrote "I restored the grid (during the initial of it)". What you mean? If you get the data from **the server side** then the grid for me is just the combination of options. If I would *save* or *restore* the grid I would don't save/restore any data, just sorting criteria, filter, current page number, which row/rows are selected and so on. **The data I would fill by sending request to the server**. It will be **the current state of data at the moment in the server database.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I did. I successfully "restored" all that you listed, and the data I'm seeing after the restoration is applicable to tge parameters I restored. . The only problem is i don't "see" the values in the toolbar, although if i'll do sort for example I will see them again (as I suppose this calls triggerToolbar). During the creation of the grid I supply all the data based in the filters to the postData param, so the grid loads with the corresponding data.

Comment: @Tal: Sorry, but I still don't understand: is the problem solved or not. How I can help you? What is your current problem?

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I solved it by iteration over the toolbar fields and pushing the values. I published it here.

Comment: @Tal: You are welcome! You wrote in your question: "I successfully achieved restoring all of those", "I do restore the filter values". I understood you so that you **can already fill the toolbar**, but you need apply the restored filter. It seems there are misunderstanding.

Comment: Right, the grid have all the values ok, just that the user don't "see" them. I had to do the below in order to let the value popup into the toolbar.

Comment: @Tal: Exactly the part of your text is unclear. If everything filled correctly then it can't be that **'the user don't "see" them'**. The only interpretation which I found was: The values were in the filter toolbar, the user could see the values in the filter toolbar, but the user can't see the corresponding results in the grid. One can execute `$grid[0].triggerToolbar();` to refresh the grid body based on the filter. I still not understand what you mean under "the value popup into the toolbar". Moreover you writes comments but ask no questions. Do you already solved the problem yourself?

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I don't take the postData AS IS because my server accept only one type of filters (and I need both toolbar and advanced desperately). Instead, I'm building it myself, call my server, and upon load complete return back the filters value to the postData.  So at gridComplete I'm restoring the postData to the state jqGrid knows, by calling grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{postData: postData });   Based on your last note, I assume that this flow is causing the toolbarfilter to some miss-behavior.