# Free jqGrid 4.13.6 - restoring the filterbar values after POST return

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

After upgrading from Free jqGrid 4.10, this [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416960/free-jqgrid-4-8-0-restore-grid-toolbarfilter-values) is not working for me anymore.

After some debug, I found out that jqGrid is restoring the value of the filter after it finish loading.

I have a special UX that is treating the same 'filter' field for two types of filtering, one that are pre-group, and one that are post-group.  I have a toggle that flips between the two mode.

I wonder if there is a way to tell jqGrid not to show the filter value if I deliberately remove it:

So if I'm doing:

```
$("#gview_"+$grid.attr('id')+' #' + inputId).val('');
```

during postData,
I don't want jqGrid to restore the value back after the postData is done.

Thanks,

Tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have old behavior, where jqGrid don't restore the filter then you can specify `loadFilterDefaults: false` option of the `filterToolbar`. You can include default options inside of `searching` parameter of jqGrid:

```
searching: {
    loadFilterDefaults: true
}
```

or inside of `$.jgrid.search`:

```
$.jgrid.search = $.jgrid.search || {};
$.jgrid.search.loadFilterDefaults = true;
```

As the result free jqGrid will don't restore any filter.

On the other side you can consider to post the demo (in jsfiddle, for example), which demonstrates what you do exactly and why the default `loadFilterDefaults: true` behavior make some problems for you.

The structure of `'filter'` field is **predefined**. I don't understand why you should save *here* some custom information (one that are pre-group, and one that are post-group). You can use **any other** custom option of jqGrid for the purpose. Probably, a good example could clear the reason.